# How to use Port Audio Libaray in XCode?

Tags: xcode, macos, audio-recording, portaudio, .a

How to use libportaudio.a library in Xcode?
First of all when I build port audio library it's type is represented as document by the Finder. When I add libportaudio.a to my Xcode projects , How should I use it in Xcode ? Is libportaudio.a enogh for using it in Xcode?
How to Include and use it in Xcode without getting errors?
Anyone who used port audio library in XCode successfully could do me a big favour and save me from a lot of troubles.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_mac_coreaudio.html) you must include `portaudio.h` and `libportaudio.a` to use the portaudio api. When I built portaudio it placed these files in `/usr/local/include/` and `/usr/local/lib/` respectively. I got my project to build by adding these paths to the Header Search Paths field in the project Build Settings tab.